# react-grid-layout breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm looking at using the [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) component but the documentation is not good when it comes to explaining the terminology.  Here are my questions:

1. What's the difference between ReactGridLayout and ResponsiveReactGridLayout?  What exactly is meant by "responsive"?
2. For ResponsiveReactGridLayout, what is meant by a "breakpoint"?  Why do we need it and how should it be set?

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at source code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not familiar with response UIs. In a nutshell, how your app adapts to being displayed at different screen sizes - typically desktop vs mobile.

Frameworks like bootstrap popularised responsive UIs by providing support out-of-the-box. The bootstrap documentation explains [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/).

In this instance, the number of grid columns changes depending upon the screen resolution (typically width in pixels), it will switch between named resolutions (breakpoints) - 'lg', 'md', 'sm', 'xs' etc.

The readme for react-grid-layout mentions [responsive props & breakpoints](https://github.com/strml/react-grid-layout#responsive-grid-layout-props).